# aspnetcore-runtime: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have a simple aspnetcore web application and below is the dockerfile,

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "samplewebapp.dll"]
```

When I'm trying to do docker build `docker build -t samplewebapp .`, I am getting below error,

> Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.651MB
>   Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
>   aspnetcore-runtime: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet
>   no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries

What this mean and what is the solution for it?

Comment: I faced similar issue, please do check the explanation posted for this error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61465075/4613139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like `microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime` is Linux container and you are running window mode, you need to switch to Linux containers.

Also according to new version you can add `--platform` but you can try to pull image first and then build the image.

[image]
[blog/docker-for-windows-18-02-with-windows-10-fall-creators-update](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-for-windows-18-02-with-windows-10-fall-creators-update/)

Another option is the experimental mode.

[image]
[docker-for-windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)

Comment: Thanks... How to know windows container for aspnetcore

Comment: sorry, you can find one below at the link https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-aspnet/ , these are window server. https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/5c25dd2ed863dfd73edb1a6381dd9635734d0e5f/3.0/aspnet/nanoserver-1809/amd64/Dockerfile