# On windows machine I get error : No matching manifest for windows/amd64

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am new to docker , recently I have installed docker on my windows 10 machine(amd/64). But while using below link I am getting issues.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-3.1

As per above link if  I try to use image pull command : 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build

**I get below error :**

No matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries

I tried below steps to resolve this :
 1. Changed docker desktop to windows containers & restarted service of docker.
 2. Also modified docker configuration file value for parameter experimental as true.

Though it did not helped me out. What I am expecting here is I want to make one windows image with dotnet core build + release setup. But currently its not working in my case. 
Probably if I change docker desktop to linux container it will work but this is not what i want.

Please do suggest solution for this, If my understanding is not clear do heighlight.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48066994/docker-no-matching-manifest-for-windows-amd64-in-the-manifest-list-entries)

Comment: Just a thought: does `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build` work? If so, then it's just that 3.0 SDK images are not on mcr...

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you're using Windows, version 1803 which is no longer supported as of November 2019.  The tag you're referencing is a multi-arch tag which the Docker client dynamically resolves to an image that matches the OS version/architecture of your Docker host machine.  Because 1803 is no longer supported, the `3.0` tag had been updated at the time support was dropped to no longer have any 1803 images associated with it.  That's why this error occurs, because there are no images supporting Windows 1803 for that tag.

To compound matters, .NET Core 3.0 is no longer supported as of March 2020.

If you *really* want to pull down a 3.0 image that works on Windows 1803, you could reference this tag: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-nanoserver-1803`.  But that is definitely not recommended because that's using an unsupported version of Windows *and* an unsupported version of .NET Core.

The recommendation is to upgrade your Docker machine to the latest supported version of Windows (1909).  It's also recommended to use .NET Core 3.1 instead of 3.0, in which case you should use `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1`.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation, it really help me to understand the cause of this error. Thank you once again.